# How to check if user input is in correct format?

Tags: bash

How can I check if user input is in correct format?

**My script:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Enter 3 numbers separated by comma'
read text
#here i want to check if user input is in correct format
```

I want user input look like this: 1,2,3.

But when user input will look e.g like this: *123* or: *1.2.3* an error text message will pop up.

Maybe I have to use arguments but I don't know how?

Answer (score 2):

see `man bash`, you can test a variable with regular expressions:

```
[[ $text =~ ^[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+$ ]] || echo wrong format
```

Example:

```
$ text=1,a,4
$ [[ $text =~ ^[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+$ ]] || echo wrong format
wrong format
$ text=1,12,34
$ [[ $text =~ ^[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+$ ]] || echo wrong format
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the input string to a pattern.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    read -p 'Enter 3 numbers separated by comma' -r text
    case $text in
     *[!,0-9]* | *,*,*,* | ,*,* | *,*, ) ;;
     *,*,* ) break;;
    esac
    echo invalid
done
```

Your processing will be much easier if you require whitespace instead of commas between the values, though.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    read -p 'Enter 3 numbers separated by space' -r first second third
    case $first,$second,$third in
     *[!,0-9]* | *,*,*,* | ,*,* | *,*, ) ;;
     *,*,* ) break;;
    esac
    echo invalid
done
```

In brief, each expression between `|` up to `)` is examined like a glob pattern (what you use for file name wildcards, like `*.png` or `?.txt`); the subpattern `[!abc]` matches a single character which is not `a`, `b`, or `c`; these consecutive characters can also be expressed as a range `[!a-c]`.

So, we reject anything which contains a character which isn't a number or a comma, anything with too many commas, anything with commas at the edges, and (implicitly, by falling through) anything with too few commas.

Comment: Can i ask what this do:
*[!,0-9]* | *,*,*,* )

Comment: Added an explanation, and a case I forgot to test for earlier.

Comment: Maybe is it possible to check it like this? But  i got error in console.


`if [$text =~ *,*,*] then echo 'correct' else echo 'not correct' fi`

Comment: You're not checking if the items are numbers; you can't really do that in a single check with just glob patterns. Also the `[ ... ]` syntax requires spaces inside the brackets.